# How to input data to multiple tables with input box

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a script to ask for user input. I know how to write the script to enter it into one cell or enter it into every empty cell at the end of the row. What I don't know is how to write it so that the user input value is inputted in one cell on two separate sheets. Can someone help me re-write this code to do that?

```
Sub AddText()
Dim myRange As String
myRange = Application.inputbox("Enter Item Number", "1")
Range("S1").Value = myRange
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualify the range with the worksheet object associated with it (this is also best practice, no matter what you're doing). I also changed the variable name to make more sense because its best practice to have meaningful and clear variable names (and a Range usually refers to one more spreadsheet cells, not a string value.

```
Sub AddText()

    Dim sInput as String
    sInput = Application.inputbox("Enter Item Number", "1")

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("S1").Value = sInput
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("S1").Value = sInput

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S1").Value = myRange
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("S1").Value = myRange
```

Comment: So simple... Thanks ChrisM!